# I can't make apps to my domine .me

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-iframe, mysite

I have a `.me` domain.

[image]

any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the protocol from your URL "`http://` so that it looks like: `www.e3la.me`. Also if you'll be using subdomains remove `www.`

Comment: see that http://www.e3la.me/wp-content/uploads/face1.jpg

Comment: do what you are asked to do! set your website url to `http://www.e3la.me`

Comment: yes i want make app to my site

Comment: huh? set the Site URL to `http://www.e3la.me`. And if that solved your problem please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer